# setSupportActionBar(toolbar) runtime Error even after importing android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

This is the main activity , as
 you can clearly see that `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` is already present.

---

```
package app.com.example.anandujjwal.zoom;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

---

main activity xml file is below.
There is runtime error at line with `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`

---

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        />

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

styles.xml is below

---

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#006400</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: If you're going to use a Toolbar as an ActionBar, your theme should extend `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. Then get rid of `getSupportActionBar().hide()`.

Comment: remove ` getSupportActionBar().hide();`

Answer (score 3):

use this in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>      
</style>
```

create colors.xml in values with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#069985</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#068573</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#fff</color>
</resources>
```

in the onCreate:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);       
    Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );
}
```

your toobar xml is right

Answer (score 1):

please try using the  AppCompatActivity instead of the ActionBarActivity.

Why do you call hide() before? You should probably remove that snippet too.
For the styles file - colors should not be hardcoded, consider creating color resources inside the color.xml.

If it doesn't help please post your logcat.

Cheers